# Curl/wget over wifi sporadically doesn't work

Tags: wifi, curl

I'm using a Raspberry Pi model B with Raspian Debian Wheezy and a Edimax wifi usb dongle. Very often all 'web' traffic stops working on my RPI. I can ssh into it, DNS works, ping works, but curl'ing or wget from my RPI does not. Other devices on the same network don't have any problems.

I've already changed power adapters to a 2.1A adapter. I've looked at dmesg, kernel.log and syslog for anything network-related and found nothing.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Here's example output:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ curl -v http://www.google.com/
* About to connect() to www.google.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 74.125.239.113...
* Connection timed out
```

Config:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.56



pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:d3:cc:77
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 80:1f:02:da:b5:54
          inet addr:192.168.1.56  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:23509 errors:0 dropped:281 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:11522 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:30942391 (29.5 MiB)  TX bytes:1481298 (1.4 MiB)



pi@raspberrypi ~ $ cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
auto wlan0

iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wpa-ssid ""
    wpa-psk ""
```

Comment: Try pinging the Google IP

Comment: @user12321 I did pinging Google, it worked fine. I can ping any site successfully.